# Send metadata to stripe payment processor

Tags: api, payment-processor, stripe

I would like to send the financial type to stripe as a metadata.

The API instructions are here:
https://stripe.com/blog/adding-context-with-metadata

I just don't know where to modify Stripe extension to add this functionnality.

Thanks.

Comment: We've done this for other bits of information to Stripe - we have a routine which updates things on a schedule to make it easier for financial reconciliation. I'll ask one of the team to add a link to a git repo with the work.

Answer (score 1):

You could start a feature request on the [Stripe-CiviCRM project page on Github](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe), and ask for guidance there.

Comment: Hi Francis - that's definitively the way to go Stripe!

Answer (score 1):

I’m also wanting to do this.

Could it be possible to use the alterPaymentProcessorParams hook to add metadata to the Stripe request?